# Error 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) and Unsupported Media Type when Sending POST Request from ReactJS to Flask Server

Tags: reactjs, http, flask

I am attempting to share a variable from ReactJS, `selectedFoodItem`, to my Flask server.

Here is my implementation. Frontend -

```
const SearchAndSuggestion = ({foodObj, foodObjF, inputF}) => {
    ...
    const [selectedFoodItem, setSelectedFoodItem] = useState("")

    ...
    useEffect(() => {

        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-recommendation?food_name=${selectedFoodItem}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ content : selectedFoodItem.toString() }),
            })
            .then((response, error) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {throw new Error(error)})
    }, [selectedFoodItem])
    
    ...
}
```

Backend -

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

@app.route('/get-recommendation', methods = ['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def recommendar():
    # data = request.get_json()
    # food_name = data.get('content')

    food_name = request.args.get('food_name')

    ...


    return json_data
```

I am trying to run this `fetch` method whenever `selectedFoodItem` gets changed. The `selectedFoodItem` change inside `<input/>` which is inside the `<form> ... </form>`. But, whenever I try to run these pieces of code together, I get different error messages from the frontend and backend. Here they are -

Frontend error(s) at `Right CLick -> Inspect -> Console` -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Failed to fetch data
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./app/today_page/search_and_suggestions/page.js:56:19)
```

Moreover, the frontend also catches error at `throw new Error("Failed to fetch data")` in my `fetch` method.

Backend loads this webpage -

```
Unsupported Media Type
Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.
```

I am unable to recognize what the problem and would like to have some help.